# Refactoring legacy java code with bad scope of variables

Tags: java, scope, refactoring

I have to deal with some old legacy code, that unfortunately had the coding style of declaring all the variables at the beginning of a method.

The code looks something like this as an example:

```
public String doSomething(boolean showStars) {
    StringBuilder builder = null;
    String result = "";
    String prefix = null;
    int i;

    try {
        prefix = "result: ";
        if (showStars) {
            builder = new StringBuilder();
            builder.append(prefix);
            for (i = 0; i < 10 ; i++) {
                builder.append('*');
            }
            result += builder.toString();
        } else {
            builder = new StringBuilder();
            builder.append(prefix);
            for (i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
                builder.append('.');
            }
            result += builder.toString();
        }

    } catch (SomeException ignored) {
    }
    return result;
}
```

Are there any best practices as of how I can transform the code most easily (automatically) to something like this?

```
public String doSomething(boolean showStars) {
    String result = "";

    try {
        String prefix = "result: ";
        if (showStars) {
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            builder.append(prefix);
            for (int i = 0; i < 10 ; i++) {
                builder.append('*');
            }
            result += builder.toString();
        } else {
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            builder.append(prefix);
            for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
                builder.append('.');
            }
            result += builder.toString();
        }

    } catch (SomeException ignored) {
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As for all such questions, make sure you have unit test coverage across this. Serious bugs can be introduced through supposedly *trivial* refactorings!

As for best practises on performing the refactoring, I'm sure a decent IDE can help you. If you delete the original declaration, your IDE will highlight the undeclared variables, and be able to prompt for and insert suitable declarations. Just double check those insertions (preferably via your unit tests above)

Comment: +1 Some IDEs can suggest only refactoring when the scope of the variable would change.  They can also detect and refactor when a variable is needlessly reused.

Comment: Deleting the original declaration and pasting it at the first shown error is how I currently do it manually, but I have to deal with 400kLOC of legacy code where basically all methods are structured like that. I need some (semi-)automatic help with that.

Comment: Don't take on the refactoring as a massive job.  Refactor the classes you need to work on today, today.  Get to the other ones when you need to work on them.

Comment: That's a very good point. Presumably this is merely an aesthetic issue ? If so, simply wait until you have to work in that area, then write the tests and resolve then. My IDE (Intellij) lets me identifiy problems sequentially in a file when I hit F2, and before I commit I make an 'F2' check and resolve outstanding stuff then

Comment: @user3771686 If you use IntelliJ you can do bulk refactoring if you are brave enough. You can change thousands of files with a couple of clicks. ;)